# Data-driven dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, data-driven

Are there any frameworks out there that allow for data-driven dependency injection (ideally in .NET)?  I'm thinking something inspired by Spring.NET for example, where you configure your object graphs in structured database tables, rather than using an XML config file.  What would be the pros and cons of configuring your application in the database rather than an XML file?

Comment: have you looked an Ninject?  Not sure if it does what you want, but it's pretty configurable.

Comment: Ninject uses a fluent interface instead of XML.  It sounds intriguing.  Robert, post an answer so you can get points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of [.Net IOC Frameworks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

and one right out microsoft's patterns and practices that I like... [Unity](http://codeplex.com/unity)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into those

Answer (score 1):

[Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) has the concept of [modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules), which allow you to conditionally configure the registrations in the container.

Modules also allow re-use of related sets of registrations.